# git error: fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/main..pipeline_creation': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am working with gitlab. I have a yml file which runs the git command diff. This command shows the difference between the two branches. here is the yml file

```
image: bitnami/git:latest
stages:
    - Test
Test_stage:
   tags:
        - docker
   stage: Test
   script:
        - echo "test stage started"
        - git diff --color=always origin/main..pipeline_creation README.md | perl -wlne 'print 
          $1 if /^\e\[32m\+\e\[m\e\[32m(.*)\e\[m$/'
```

when i run this in the pipeline i am getting this error:

```
Created fresh repository.
Checking out e33fa512 as pipeline_creation...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo "test stage started"
test stage started
$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at e33fa51)
  remotes/origin/pipeline_creation
$ git diff main..pipeline_creation README.md
fatal: ambiguous argument 'main..pipeline_creation': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Locally the command is working fine but when I run it in pipeline its not showing the expected result. Does  someone know what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Since `pipeline_creation` seems to be the branch that is checked out, are you sure your repo for the job contains a `origin/main`? What is the output if you use the syntax without the "..", like `git diff --color=always origin/main pipeline_creation README.md`?

Comment: still getting the same error. Used git diff main..pipeline_creation README.md

Comment: i have updated the output with git branch -a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `git branch -a` shows the cause of the problem: The repo does not have any local branches and it only has one remote branch `remotes/origin/pipeline_creation`. You need to fetch the `main` branch first before you can use it in the `git diff` command:

```
git fetch --depth=1 origin main
```